# How to make sure that the image will display in fabric JS

Tags: javascript, image, fabricjs

So I have a bunch of PNG images that when put together will make a cue case, But I noticed that sometimes the images will display sometimes not but they are selectable. How can I make sure that all of the images that I put through code will be displayed? I'm using fabric.Image.fromUrl().

I tried the img.onload but for some reason it didn't solved the problem. I also tried for looping to put the images in order but still some won't display but is selectable and if I refresh the browser sometimes some images will be displayed sometimes won't.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.